# Need guidance on creating a Public Key Infrastructure from an online provider

Tags: ssl, lets-encrypt, pki

I want to set up secure TLS for my docker hosts as described [here](https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/blob/master/swarm/configure-tls.md) which describes creating your own Public Key Infrastructure (PKI). For production servers it is inadvisable to use your own Certificate Authority. Are there any online Certificate Authorities that can provide the public/private keys (.pem and .csr files) for me? I have been looking at [Lets Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/), as I know they can provide SSL certificates, but I cannot find any guidance on providing a PKI.

**Edit:**

This is the setup I'm attempting to create:

[image]

Can Let's Encrypt or any other online service, provide the necessary key/cert files as represented in this image.

Comment: Let's Encrypt __is__ a PKI.  You use their tools to create the private key and CSR within your docker instance and the tool sends the CSR to Let's Encrypt who sign the request and return the certificate automatically to your instance.  It can even install it in some cases.  Please edit your question to list the additional features you need that Let's Encrypt cannot provide.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure if Let's Encrypt cannot provide the necessary tokens to secure the Docker daemon. To secure the Docker Daemon I need to provide public/private keys and certificates (ca.cert)  for the Docker CLI, Manager and Worker nodes. I've edited the question to hopefully add clarification.

Comment: I think you're failing to understand some PKI basics here.  The _private_ key doesn't leave the entity that owns it - that's why it's called a private key.  The entity uses its public/private key pair to generate a CSR, which is sent (alone) to the CA for signing.

Comment: Let's Encrypt will work if all the entities are public facing - that is, they have a global DNS entry.  Let's Encrypt won't sign a certificate for a private namespace such as 'example.com` as there are many of those in the world.  If the latter is what you're after then you can either create your own PKI or choose a managed PKI service which can work with internal networks.  If you do opt to create an internal one, I'd advise against using OpenSSL in production as there is no governance around it.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. The swarm manager and workers are public facing but not the Remote Docker Client. This is a runner in a Gitlab CI which needs to deploy to my swarm manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Ascertia services to setup your pki structure.
https://www.ascertia.com/
They have a full PKI standard service for CA and Key Management.